# Analysing system calls

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, system-calls

As a part of syscall analysis, I would like to find what all syscalls are being invoked in a system from the boot to the shutdown of the system. How would I do this? Need help.

Comment: Isn't there a way to narrow your search? Tracing **all** syscalls in a system will make it very slow.

Comment: Obviously, that could be made by considering only some system calls.

Comment: not very slow... just stop it.  There's a quantum mechanics issue in doing so.  What would be the interface to activate such a thing? a system call? if so, should this syscall be traced? If so, aren't we getting in some kind of recursive deep hole?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at SystemTap. https://sourceware.org/systemtap/

It's a very powerful trace/debug framework. You can easily probe all syscalls with a few lines of stap script.

For example: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/syscalltimes

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to trace the syscall, when you run the application, run it with "strace" command, it will list the syscall that program or application has used.

Comment: The questioner wants to trace *all* syscalls from *all* applications. Not a single application. So not easily done with strace.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://lttng.org/) will provide a good knowledge on tracing syscalls on different runlevels. Actually, this will trace all the user and kernel events but this we could trace only syscalls by providing options.

Refs: http://lwn.net/Articles/492296/

Comment: Link only answers are not quite appreciated. It would be good if you add some explanation.